# How do you horizontally autoscroll a right-aligned UILabel to the right?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to make a simple iOS calculator and need to get the label that shows the calculation to automatically scroll horizontally to the right.

I can get it to scroll correctly if it's left aligned when I embed a UILabel inside of a UIScrollView, but what I need is for it to automatically scroll to the right as the user inputs numbers.

[Calculator mock-up where the scrollable label is circled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTiN8.png)

Comment: You put the scroll view _inside_ the label? Why not make them siblings? As for making it scroll automatically, it may be easier to use a `UITextView` (which is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, then call `scrollRangeToVisible(range)` after you append each string.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I figured it out.